# Running an ASP.NET Core web app in GitHub Codespaces gives 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, .net-core, codespaces

I'm trying to get GitHub Codespaces working with a simple asp.net core web app.

I've created a new asp.net core web app (`dotnet new webapp`), confirmed it all works locally, and then added it to an Organization GitHub repo.

From here, I open the repo in Codespaces, in the browser.

I've configured the container for C# and Sql, my docker files are unchanged from the ones that are generated.

I can build fine, then I `dotnet run` from the Terminal and I can see the app starts up fine:

````
Info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]```
````

I also get a message about port forwarding, and I can see that port forward set up:

[image: ![enter image description here]

However, when I try that URL, I get an NGINX `502 Bad Gateway` error from the 5001 port. From the 5000 port URL it just tries to redirect me to `https://localhost:5001`.

Am I missing some part of setup?

### Things I've tried

- Adding `forwardedPorts` to the `devcontainer.json` file.
- Toggling the port forward to public / private
- Changing the Port Protocol to https
- Logging in and out of github, and rebuilding the devcontainer many times.

Comment: Did you use dockerfile? You can read this article to configure it, which may help you:https://github.com/dotnet/docfx/issues/3615#issuecomment-451664865

Comment: It generates a docker file so I assume the answer is yes?. I can’t see any reference to nginx in the config, the only way I know it’s using nginx is the error message.

Answer (score 2):

Cross-posting https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/7116, where this seems to be discussed more heavily. We can update this when we've got a firm answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on this project on Codespaces and got the same error: https://github.com/LinkedInLearning/hands-on-aspnet-razor-pages-3084715

Commenting this line number 16 helped solve the issue.

[image]

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.